# Is there a way to pre fetch calls from a library in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-google-charts

I am using GeoChart from react-google-charts (https://github.com/RakanNimer/react-google-charts) and I see that there are many scripts that load after everything was done. In my case https://www.gstatic.com/charts/geochart/10/info/mapList.js is loading at the end, is there a way to prioritize when a script is loading?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `next/script` component.

```
import Script from 'next/script'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" />
    </>
  )
}
```

With next/script, you decide when to load your third-party script by using the `strategy` property

```
<Script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js" strategy="lazyOnload" />
```

There are four different loading strategies that can be used:

- `beforeInteractive`: Load before the page is interactive
- `afterInteractive`: (default) Load immediately after the page becomes interactive
- `lazyOnload`: Load during idle time
- `worker`: (experimental) Load in a web worker

For more information, checkout the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script).

Comment: Thank you! I have used Next.js Script but even though I am loading the scripts earlier, react-google-charts still makes a the same requests, that's my issue now.

Comment: You don't have control over which/how many requests are made, you can only choose how to defer them to optimize UX.